# moving an item from one site to a second to a third = unfollowable

Tags: bug, status-declined, migration

This question:

- [started on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285744/5-bars-till-connected-then-1-bar)
- [got moved to ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/54812/5-bars-till-connected-then-1-bar)
- [got moved to SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/23535/5-bars-till-connected-then-1-bar)

The page on StackOverflow includes a 'migrated to' block, but the ServerFault page only includes a 'migrated from' block - there's no 'migrated to' block to follow it to SuperUser.

Comment: I think it would *hilarious* if this ended up on Meta. Just throwing that out there.

Comment: TXI: MAKE IT HAPPEN. YES WE CAN.

Comment: Oh my. I see it ended up here. Now stop teasing the animal children and put it back!

Comment: Now that's just cruel. Heehee...

Comment: Kyle is a bad influence.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah... The "migrated" indicator feels rather tacked-on. In addition to only keeping track of a single migration, if you close a migrated question the timestamp for the migration changes to the close time.

I gotta figure they were reluctant to add a new table or column to the existing table, and instead they're piggybacking on close status or something...